# What role does enthalpy play when I am boiling pasta?

Tags: thermodynamics

It has been a long time and I apologize about such a basic question. I always thought that the energy of the water, including the heat used to boil it, is important to boiling pasta. That is why the package states boil pasta in "XX" quarts of water for "XX" minutes. I thought that the energy of that combination of time and mass was the energy required to cook the pasta...or any food...

Comment: ...and your actual question is?